# Unexpected Behavior in typeahead - is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I have an input using typeahead as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="unit" name="unit" class="form-control form-input" ng-model="item.unit"
            autocomplete="off" 
            typeahead-min-length="0" 
            uib-typeahead="unit as unit.symbol for unit in units | typeaheadFilter:{'symbol':$viewValue} | orderBy:smartOrder" 
            typeahead-template-url="unit-template.html" />
```

And here is the template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="unit-template.html">
    <a tabindex="-1">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" ng-bind-html="match.model.symbol | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
            <span class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1" ng-bind-html="match.model.name  | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
</script>
```

my units collection has two items:

```
name=kilogram symbol=kg
name=litre symbol=L
```

At first look I thought that typeahead works fine.

But when I tried the below key combinations, I found a bug.

## Case: 1

**Working:**

When I type kg in typeahead and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> twice, the item.unit property has value:

```
Object {_id: "58cd0cdf28ea727c68be7ac3", name: "Kilogram", symbol: "kg", numberOfDecimalPlaces: 3, isSystemUnit: false…}
```

**Not working:**

But when I type kg in typeahead and hit <kbd>esc</kbd> and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, the item.unit property has value:

```
kg
```

## Case:2

**Working:**

When I type kg in typeahead and hit <kbd>tab</kbd> twice the focus goes away from the control. Now item.unit property has value:

```
Object {_id: "58cd0cdf28ea727c68be7ac3", name: "Kilogram", symbol: "kg", numberOfDecimalPlaces: 3, isSystemUnit: false…}
```

And then if I delete the text in typeahead by using <kbd>delete</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd> key, then if I move focus away from typeahead then item.unit is

```
undefined.
```

**Not working:**

When I type kg in typeahead and hit tab twice the focus goes away from the control. Now item.unit property has value:

```
Object {_id: "58cd0cdf28ea727c68be7ac3", name: "Kilogram", symbol: "kg", numberOfDecimalPlaces: 3, isSystemUnit: false…}
```

And then if I delete the text in typeahead by selecting the text and then using <kbd>delete</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd> key, then I move focus away from typeahead, then item.unit is still having value:

```
Object {_id: "58cd0cdf28ea727c68be7ac3", name: "Kilogram", symbol: "kg", numberOfDecimalPlaces: 3, isSystemUnit: false…}
```

I have also raised an issue on their [github page](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6497).

**Plunker:**

Here is the link to plunker that reproduces the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/FIPANC3CcliNOeHHANxF

Comment: Note "Kiogram" should be "Kilogram"

Comment: create a plunker/fiddle if possible?

Comment: I think esc removes focus from the input, then the tab will not work the same way you want it to work. also need a fiddle so I can see it myself.

Comment: @tanmay I have updated my question with a plunker link.

Comment: @praszyk I have updated my question with a plunker link.

Comment: @KScandrett It was a typo. Updated question. Also added a link to plunker reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a bug with type-ahead

- In *non-working case 1*: you are effectively saying cancel type-ahead (which is what <kbd>esc</kbd> does) and then your code says display whatever is bound to the `input` element, which in this case is just whatever you typed in - "kg". That is the expected behaviour (for the given code).

  In other words, you'd get exactly the same result if type-ahead wasn't installed.
- In *non-working case 2*, it depends on how you move away after deleting - if you are using <kbd>tab</kbd> twice, type-ahead has the default suggestion selected of 'kg' so first <kbd>tab</kbd> picks it and then the second moves focus, so I'd expect it to be set to the 'kg' object. If however you are clicking somewhere else after the delete/backspace then the value is the empty string '', which also is what I'd expect given that you're displaying the property bound to the `input`.

So the real question is what do you want to happen when these things occur?

**EDIT:**

To return a matching object in *non-working case 1* you can do the following - when leaving the field if `$scope.unit` is not set to an object perform a lookup in the array:

```
$scope.unitLostFocus = function(unit) {
  if (typeof unit !== "object") { // typed text so try to match in our array
    var res = jQuery.grep($scope.units, function(n) {
      return ( n.symbol.toLowerCase() === unit.toLowerCase() );
    });
    if (res.length)
      $scope.unit = res[0]; // first match
    else 
      $scope.unit = undefined; // whatever you want to do here when there's no match
  }
  console.log($scope.unit);
};
```

Updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8YsecsgToP8dtwYHbhD4?p=preview

Comment: OK. If you think that current behavior of typeahead is fine, then that's not my requirement. My requirement is that: If I type kg and then press esc key and then tab key, I want the value of variable bound to input to be Kilogram Object instead of text kg. And second non-working case cannot be reproduced. I will take a look at it.

Comment: I was out for work from last four days. So, I cannot check your answer. Now, I checked it. It works fine. Thank you for the answer.